# How to retrieve the list of all storage adapters on an ESXi host using pyvmomi?

Tags: pyvmomi

I recently started using pyvmomi to automate few tasks.

I need to retrieve the list of storage adapters using pyvmomi.
However, I did not find examples or APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrote a python package called [vmwc](https://github.com/jossef/vmwc) to provide a simple VMWare SDK client for Python (it basically wraps pyvmomi with high level functionality).

The following snippet is from it's source code. This function enumerates the ESXi's datastores + disk information ([source](https://github.com/jossef/vmwc/blob/master/vmwc/__init__.py#L155))

```
def get_datastores(self):

    # Search for all ESXi hosts
    objview = self._content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(self._content.rootFolder, [vim.HostSystem], True)
    esxi_hosts = objview.view
    objview.Destroy()

    for esxi_host in esxi_hosts:

        # All Filesystems on ESXi host
        storage_system = esxi_host.configManager.storageSystem
        host_file_sys_vol_mount_info = storage_system.fileSystemVolumeInfo.mountInfo

        for host_mount_info in host_file_sys_vol_mount_info:

            # Extract only VMFS volumes
            if host_mount_info.volume.type != "VMFS":
                continue

            datastore = {
                'name': host_mount_info.volume.name,
                'disks': [item.diskName for item in host_mount_info.volume.extent],
                'uuid': host_mount_info.volume.uuid,
                'capacity': host_mount_info.volume.capacity,
                'vmfs_version': host_mount_info.volume.version,
                'local': host_mount_info.volume.local,
                'ssd': host_mount_info.volume.ssd
            }

            yield datastore
```

---

BTW, this is how you would do this using [vmwc](https://github.com/jossef/vmwc)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from vmwc import VMWareClient


def main():
    host = '192.168.1.1'
    username = '<username>'
    password = '<password>'

    with VMWareClient(host, username, password) as client:
        for datastore in client.get_datastores():
            print (datastore)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: First of all, congrats on the Python package implementation!
I've tried running the above code as I was also investigating on retrieving LUN IDs for datastores, however from what I see some of the attributes might not be properly populated:

```File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vmwc/__init__.py", line 166, in get_datastores
    host_file_sys_vol_mount_info = storage_system.fileSystemVolumeInfo.mountInfo
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mountInfo'```

Any ideas on how to fix this one?